# How to guarantee class loading

Tags: java

I have a class whose initialization takes quite a bit of time; it invokes a server and that server takes several minutes to become ready.

Methods on that class aren't called for quite a while and they are always called from a class that is automatically loaded on start-up.  My set-up is like this:

```
class SlowToStartUp {
  public static void init() {
     // do nothing
  }

  static {
    initiateConnectionToServer()
  }

  public static V invokeServer() {
     waitForServerToConnect();
     return valueFromServer();
  }
}


class AlwaysLoaded {
  static {
     SlowToStartUp.init();
  }

  public void someMethod() {
     V v = SlowToStartUp.invokeServer();
  }
```

This strikes me as structurally correct.  If there were no `init()` function at all, `initiateConnectionToServer()` wouldn't be called until `someMethod()` needed the class for the first time, and then there would be an unnecessary (and in my system, unacceptable) delay.

If I put the `initiateConnectionToServer()` call in `init()`, the interface would be more fragile (since the call might be forgotten).

But now I am wondering if I have outsmarted myself.  The compiler can see that `init()` is empty.  Could it not just optimize the call away?  It does not do so now, but it that guaranteed?

I tried marking `init()` as `volatile`, but that is not allowed.

I am considering putting the actual initialization into `init()`, making sure it is idempotent, and invoking it from a static block, just to be on the safe side, but I thought I would ask for advice first.

Comment: Could you not do the initialization in a class constructor, and then simply delay instantiation of your class until it was needed? This would avoid having to remember to invoke a static init() class, but would be problematic if you required a quick response from your class.

Comment: That's exactly it.  The program is started midnight Friday.  A human being uses it Monday morning.  I don't want her to have to wait two minutes while a connection is being made.

Comment: Would it be feasible to instantiate your object when the program first starts? If you can guarantee that no one will need it for some time, you could always wait until the main class loading is finished before invoking the constructor.

Comment: You could use a singleton pattern instead of static methods and fetch the singleton instance as soon as your application starts. That would force the JVM to create the instance and thus run your initialization code.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta -- you know, I like that.  Maybe I'll go with that.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative approach would be to refactor to a singleton class instead of a bunch of static method. The singleton will then be created at startup and your initialization code would run right away.

```
public class SlowPokeSingleton {
  private SlowPokeSingleton() { /* execute init code */ }

  // created at startup
  private final static SlowPokeSingleton instance = new SlowPokeSingleton();

  public static SlowPokeSingleton instance() { return instance; }
}
```

You will need to call `instance()` to make sure the instance is actually created. You can add that to your server startup to be safe.

Comment: I'm _am_ 100% sure I need to call instance() to make sure the instance is created. I have been fooling around with this for _days_.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tenuous answer to my own question. The events that trigger class initialization are specified in [JLS 12.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.1).

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and **a static method declared by T is invoked**.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top-level class, and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T is executed.

It seems to me that a compiler that optimized away an empty static function would violate the provision I marked in bold.

Comments welcome.

Comment: A static initializer is not the same as a static method. Static initializers trigger under the same conditions that the class itself would be initialized, but if there is nothing in there then there is no reason to keep it. Likewise, if your static init() method is empty and never invoked, there is no reason to keep it, either, but are you sure that the compiler removes it?

Comment: The static function I was referring to `init()`.  I would think that optimizing it away would violate the explicit rule.  I am sure the compiler I am using right now does _not_ remove it, but I did not want to depend on a (potentially) transitory behavior.

Comment: I wouldn't think any compiler would optimize away a public static method, even if empty, but I cannot tell you with 100% certainty. For your particular case, however, I would argue the point is moot: initialize your class in the constructor and create a new instance at program startup, either normally or as a singleton. Do you have reasons to do otherwise, or are you more interested in the specification?

Comment: @Brian, does "not thinking of it" count as a reason to do otherwise?  As soon as Giovanni "Johnny Thump" Botta made the suggestion that I use a singleton, I went and changed the real-life code to exactly that, although an in-house reviewer suggested I change again to use Spring Singletons, a pattern our web-server supports.  _Now_ I am mostly interested in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Giovanni Botta:

> You could use a singleton pattern instead of static methods and fetch
>   the singleton instance as soon as your application starts. That would
>   force the JVM to create the instance and thus run your initialization
>   code. –  Giovanni Botta

Specifically:

1) Put the "time consuming" part of your initialization into a private, static "init()" method.

2) Make your class's constructor "private".

3) Instead of a constructor, provide a public static "getInstance()" method to fetch a reference to your (already-initialized) singleton instance.

4) Your other methods can be non-static, if you wish.